# TypeORM - Get Matching (and related) rows form Postgres

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am not sure if the title clearly defines the problem so I'll try explaining it here.

I have 2 tables, a `Users` table and a `Conversations` table.

`Users` and `Conversations` have a `Many-to-Many` relationship.

**Users Entity:**

*Excluding other columns*

```
@ManyToMany(() => Conversation, (conversationEntity) => conversationEntity.participants)
    conversations: Conversation[];
```

**Conversations Entity:**

*Excluding other columns*

```
@ManyToMany(() => User, userEntity => userEntity.conversations)
    @JoinTable()
    participants: User[];
```

Data inside the join table looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want to get all the conversations for a specific user. But I also want to get the related rows. For example in the image above, I want to get both the rows because both rows belong to the same conversation. But since I am searching based on userId, the query skips the rows that don't match the userId.

Here's the TypeORM query I am using:

```
const [results, totalCount] = await this.conversationsRepo
  .createQueryBuilder('conversations')
  .leftJoin('conversations.participants', "participants")
  .andWhere('participants.id = :userId', {userId})
  .addSelect(['participants.fullName', 'participants.id'])
  .getManyAndCount();
```

Is there any way I can get the other participant too? I am new to TypeORM and also Postgres, so I am not sure if there's a better approach to defining the relations here. Open to suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is making 1 more table such as UserConversations to save the many to many of 2 tables User and Conversation. Let's say:

In User entity:

```
@OneToMany()
public userConversations: UserConversation[]
```

In Conversation entity:

```
@OneToMany()
public userConversations: UserConversation[]
```

In UserConversation entity:

```
@ManyToOne()
public user: User
@ManyToOne()
public conversation: Conversation
```